# URL containing opening without closing bracket doesn't work inline

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

If an URL contains only an opening bracket (`(`), but no closed bracket (`)`) and you try to link to it inline (`[like this](http://www.example.org/opening_bracket:_()`), the markdown doesn't work. The closing bracket is seen as part of the URL and therefore the whole syntax as unfinished.

Linking like the button does it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Markdown works.

If you ever have a URL with an unpaired parenthesis (brackets and braces aren't the case), encode it or put it at the end of the post

```
[Solution 1](http://example.com/Unpaired_%28)
[Solution 2][2]

  [2]: http://example.com/Unpaired_(
```

Comment: But it could work better. Or is there a case where detecting that would create a problem?

Comment: @Fabian Then how to handle well-paired parentheses?

Comment: Just like now. The last closing bracket ends the URL, no matter what is in between.

Comment: @Fabian The problem is, we can't handle both cases as of now. The parentheses pairing algorithm can't detect when an opening parenthesis needs its pair.

Comment: So you mean that it first detects parenthesis pairs and then the other markdown (links and so on) based on that? Then a bigger change is requires, but it's still a valid bug. It can then be decided to not get fixed, but it **is** a bug.